# 12-week staffing forecast LINQ query

Tags: c#, performance, datetime, linq

I have a LINQ query that I am having trouble optimizing and takes about 5.5 seconds to run. I am using a view called StaffingResourceData and a table called StaffingForecasts.

Each StaffingResource has a ResourceId, a Division, and a Type. A StaffingForecast has a ResourceId, Project, Date (represents a Monday of a week), Hours. A StaffingResource can have 0-many StaffingForecasts.

For each StaffingResource, I need a list of their total forecasted hours for the next 12 weeks. Here is what I have right now:

```
// Get list of dates
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
var start = Utilities.GetStartOfWeek(DateTime.Today);
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    dates.Add(start.AddDays(i * 7));
}
var end = dates[11];

// Get resources
var resources = (from r in context.StaffingResourceDatas
                 where r.EmployeeId != null
                     && !exclusionList.Contains(r.ResourceTitleId)
                 join f in context.StaffingForecasts.Where(x => x.Date >= start && x.Date <= end) on r.ResourceId equals f.ResourceId into g1
                 from f in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 group new { f.Date, f.Hours } by r into g2
                 select new ChartResourceModel
                 {
                     ResourceId = g2.Key.ResourceId,
                     Division = g2.Key.ResourceDivision,
                     Type = g2.Key.ResourceType,
                     Dates = dates.Select(d => new ChartDateModel
                     {
                         Date = d,
                         Available = (g2.Where(f => f.Date == d).Any() ? g2.Where(f => f.Date == d).Sum(f => f.Hours) : 0) < 24
                     }).ToList()
                 })
               .ToList();
```

Any ideas on how I could speed this up?

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes in place on your database tables?

Comment: What happens if you remove the inner `ToList` call? Also, if you can and if it's appropriate, try creating a view in the database that does the various joins and filter data on that view. My thought is that somewhere in the query you're dealing with an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IQueryable` ([see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/766541/IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable) for the difference between the two).

Comment: Regarding the inner `ToList` call, I guess `Dates` is a `List` in the `ChartResourceModel`. Can you change the type to `IEnumerable`?

Comment: What ORM are you using? Entity Framework? How does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: If you have the option, write the query as is in SQL and obtain the execution plan to look for any missing indexes. This query should not take long to execute at all unless you are trawling a large number StaffingForecast rows, in which case there is probably a missing index.

Answer (score 2):

You are combining an `IQueryable` with a local sequence, `dates`. It *is* possible to do that, but Entity Framework<sup>1</sup> needs a lot of code to convert the sequence into something that behaves like a SQL table. I'm sure this is a major performance killer.

From what I see, you can do without this local sequence. You know the begin and end date. So it's possible to get the forecasts between those dates. If you group those forecasts by their `Date`, you achieve the same grouping:

```
from r in context.StaffingResourceDatas 
where r.EmployeeId != null && !exclusionList.Contains(r.ResourceTitleId)
let forecasts = context.StaffingForecasts
                       .Where(f => r.ResourceId == f.ResourceId
                                && f.Date >= start && f.Date <= end)
select new ChartResourceModel
{
    ResourceId = r.Key.ResourceId,
    Division = r.Key.ResourceDivision,
    Type = r.Key.ResourceType,
    Dates = (from fc in forecasts
             group fc by d.Date into fcg
             select new ChartDateModel
             {
                 Date = fcg.Key,
                 Available = fcg.Sum(f => f.Hours) < 24
             })
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume this is EF, because Linq-to-Sql doesn't allow local sequences in a LINQ query.